# Changing options for presentation.saveas pdf

Tags: powershell, pdf, com, powerpoint, ghostscript

I'm using the following powershell to save a PPT as a PDF

```
  $app = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
  $presentation = $app.Presentations.open($FileName,-1,$null,0) #Open filename, boolReadOnly -1 = MSOTrue, boolOpenUntitled, boolWithWindow 0 = MSOFalse
  $presentation.SaveAs(($outFile).Value,32) #ppSaveAsPDF
  [Void]$Presentation.Close()
  [Void]$app.Quit() 
  [Void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($app)
```

It does save the file without issue, however some of the files that it produces are a little large. I took a look and in powerpoint there is the option when saving to PDF, to use minimum size:
[image: Mimimum size]
There are also options in Tools to change the image compression:
[image: Compress images]

Is there a way to set these variables for powerpoint by default? Better yet, a way to set this in the saveas command?

I've also had some luck with GhostScript using the following command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.21\bin\gswin64.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=Outfile.pdf Infile.pdf
```

But I would really like to avoid installing ghostscript. Can this be done using a DLL or something?

Comment: If this is for an open source application of your own you could use the Ghostscript DLL, provided you adhere to the licence. The sample Ghostscript executable just uses the DLL anyway.

Comment: Looks like GhostScriptSharp might do the trick, but I'm struggling to get it installed and working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use PowerPoint's ExportAsFixedFormat method rather than SaveAs. It gives you far more control over the result.  This MSDN article describes all the parms:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/PowerPoint-VBA/articles/presentation-exportasfixedformat-method-powerpoint

The main one you'll be interested in is Intent.

The compression options you mention control how much (and whether) PPT compresses images on saving the file as a PPTX but that could certainly (if indirectly) affect the size of PDFs created from the PPTX. There's no way to control the compression settings other than by tweaking the registry, and in order for that to work, you'd have to do it prior to starting PPT.

Try setting the compression to your taste, then checking here:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\X.0\PowerPoint\Options

(where X = 14 for Office 2010, 15 for 2013, 16 for 2016)

Look for a DWORD called AutomaticPictureCompressionDefault; I think that's what will control the compression level.

If the presentation you're working with has already had pictures added and has been saved at least once, changing the compression level may have no further effect